# The server says: Undefined index Sec-WebSocket-Key during handshake process when I access the site from mobile. From the same pc (localhost) its ok

Tags: php, websocket, handshake

The server says: Undefined index Sec-WebSocket-Key during handshake process when I access the site from mobile. From the same pc (localhost) its ok

```
function doHandshake($received_header,$client_socket_resource, $host_name, $port) {
            $headers = array();
            $lines = preg_split("/\r\n/", $received_header);
            foreach($lines as $line)
            {
                $line = chop($line);
                if(preg_match('/\A(\S+): (.*)\z/', $line, $matches))
                {
                    $headers[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
                }
            }

            $secKey = $headers['Sec-WebSocket-Key'];
            $secAccept = base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($secKey . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11')));
            $buffer  = "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\n" .
            "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" .
            "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
            "WebSocket-Origin: $host_name\r\n" .
            "WebSocket-Location: ws://$host_name:$port/demo/shout.php\r\n".
            "Sec-WebSocket-Accept:$secAccept\r\n\r\n";
            socket_write($client_socket_resource,$buffer,strlen($buffer));
        }
```

Comment: I just followed this code.
https://phppot.com/php/simple-php-chat-using-websocket/
and trying to understand how it works but faced this issue.

Answer (score -1):

You need to replace $hostname "localhost" with the ip address assigned to your computer.
You can visit https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/faq/838/ for finding out ip address of your host computer.